# Создание защищённой административной панели для сайта

Tags: frontend, backend

В административной панели будет просто таблица загруженная из БД, админ может изменять, добавлять и удалять элементы. Каким способом или каким инструментом лучше воспользоваться, что бы:

1. Можно было настроить путь к админке (вместо http://mysite/admin можно было сделать например http://mysite/blabla/lala/admin).
2. Была возможность по максимуму обезопасить вход в панель, так как логина и пароля маловато. Например какие то доп проверки

Также я не могу понять, считается ли нормальным для сайта, если любой пользователь может попасть на страницу логина для админа. Может вместо того, что бы возиться с путем для админки, лучше как то вычислять пользователя по айпи или что-то в этом роде, и просто закрывать доступ. Если да, то что можете что то посоветовать на этот счет. Заранее спасибо

Comment: «логина и пароля маловато» — почему это?

Comment: можно положить панель отдельно от основного сайта и url по которому она должна открываться описать в настройках web-сервера. кроме того там же в настройках веб сервера можно указать для этого пути требовать наличия клиентского сертификата. И да, опять же в настройках веб сервера можно указать даже список ip с которого имеется доступ к данному разделу. Из инструментов понадобиться текстовый редактор, что бы править конфиг веб-сервера и возможно openssl, если решите использовать сертификаты

Comment: Сделайте маршрутизацию любую до панели - раз. Сделайте доступ по ip - два, можно сделать базовую авторизацию apache - три.